# SQL - Query linked information between two items

Tags: mysql, sql

If I had two columns of first and last names. And through SQL, I wanted to link their names together by finding similar first or last names.

Example: We start with John Doe & Susan Poole.

Could it find a user named Paul Doe and then Paul Poole to complete the link?

Answer: John Doe to Paul Doe to Paul Poole to Susan Poole.

Is this something that can be done in SQL?

Still new to SQL.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Can u make it more clear by putting some sample table and the desired output?

If you are talking about querying all the names in table with same last name or first name, always go with LIKE keyword

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE lastname LIKE 'paul'

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully get the question so please explain more.

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE `firstname` = 'Doe' OR `firstname` = 'Poole';
```

will return all the Doe and Poole family.

By adding

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE `firstname` = 'Doe' OR `firstname` = 'Poole' ORDER BY `lastname`;
```

will return all families in order.

Using wildcards

```
SELECT * from `table` WHERE `lastname` LIKE '%oe%';
```

will return all the Does

Comment: I think I just needed more time to learn about SQL.  I think what I'll be doing is creating a stored procedure that will create temp tables for each of the starting options and look for matches from those.  And then I can get more intricate and indepth based on whats in those temp tables.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.